# Superposition of two cached maps with Android SDK

Tags: android, cache, arcgis-android

I'm developping an Android Application with ArcGIS Runtime For Android, i wish to know if it's possible to superpose 2 cached maps from 2 diffrent WMS and store them in mobil.

Comment: Create two createTileCache using the code https://developers.arcgis.com/android/sample-code/export-tile-cache/ this stores wms locally on users devices for offline usage.